# xcode4.2.1 - storyboard - Navigation controller - Title bar color

Tags: xcode, storyboard, titlebar, navigationcontroller

I am designing an app with storyboard with minimal coding. So, I am designing everything using views and buttons without the need for header files.

What is the easiest way to change the default blue title bar color to black with minimal coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your Info.plist file

[image]

Answer (score 30):

Select the nav controller in the left scene selector.
[image]

And click on the "Style" drop down menu and select the one you want.

Answer (score 4):

Select "Navigation Controller > Navigation Bar" in the storyboard and use the attributes inspector.

[image]

Comment: Strange, in XCode 4.3.2 I just see Simulated Metrics in the attributes inspector. None of what's in your screenshot.

Comment: I just fixed the answer.  It should have specified to select the **Navigation Bar**.  Notice the jump bar at top of the image has the Navigation Bar showing.

Comment: And of course, it is not possible to actually click on the navigation bar to select it, that would be too easy. You need to click on "Navigation Controller" in the jump bar to bring up the menu, follow the small arrow, and select "Navigation Bar" in the submenu.